# ErrorException Undefined variable

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have massage error like this  ErrorException
Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\resources\views\petani\index.blade.php). how i to solve it ?

Controller :

```
public function index(){

$post = Desa::all();    
return view('petani.index',compact ('desas')); 
}
```

Route :
    `Route::get('petani', 'BiodataController@index');`

Index :

```
    <?php
        $no = 1;
        ?>
         @foreach ($posts as $post) 
    <td>{{$no++}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->nama}}</td>

    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn"><a href="{{ URL::to('coba/test/'.$post->id.'/edit') }}" >Edit</a></button>
         {{ Form::open(['url' => 'coba/test/'.$post->id, 'method' => 'DELETE']) }}
           {{ Form::button('delete', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn']) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}

    </td>

  </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `compact('desas')`, type `['posts' => $post]` and you're good to go

Comment: Even though your answer may (or may not, I don't know) be correct, I think a bit of context wouldn't hurt. For example, why doesn't `compact('desas')` work and how is `['posts' => $post]` solving the problem?

Comment: posts on ['posts' => $post ] its mean table on database ? @KenS.

Comment: the second parameter of view($viewname, $options) takes an array. You were giving compact('desas'), as you want to use $posts in your view (which you iterate through), you need to give an array who has a key named "posts" ( an alias from key to var will be done, so if a key is named "welcome" you'll get a var $welcome in the view) which is what you were missing. The $post contains your table rows, and you put them into a key "posts", used by $posts in view to be iterated. more informations here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views

Comment: thanks .. i should to reading laravel docs from now :)) thanks @HugoRegibo